# Formatear decimal como moneda y remover ceros a la derecha

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando transformar los valores en una columna `DECIMAL (10, 4)` a moneda de México (`,` para separar centenas y `.` para separar valores decimales).

[Encontré una forma para quitar los ceros a la derecha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length), sin embargo, si la uso con el valor ya formateado, este me toma la `,` como separador de decimales y me quita todo lo que esta a la derecha.

Ejemplo:

`SELECT FORMAT(89320.0000, 4, "es-MX") as resultado;`  Me da `89,320.0000`, pero si uso `SELECT TRIM(FORMAT(89320.0000, 4, "es-MX")) + 0 as resultado;` me da `89`.

¿Hay alguna forma de prevenir esto? ¿O lo mejor seria pasar el número sin formato y tratarlo en el front?

Mi versión de MySQL es la 5.6.

Comment: Siempre es mejor tratarlo en el front... es mas.. que pasa si quisieras sumar esos valores en el front? no podrias, porque ya vienen formateados... el formato, es un problema del front.. no de lo que esta en el medio...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si bien estoy 100% de acuerdo con el [comentario de @gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526258/formatear-decimal-como-moneda-y-remover-ceros-a-la-derecha#comment932134_526258), una forma de llegar al resultado es:

Por ejemplo, tenemos que:

```
Set @number = 89320.0200;
Set @locale = 'en_US';
```

1. Obtenemos la parte entera del número y la formateamos

   ```
   FORMAT(FLOOR(@number), 0, @locale)
   # 89,320
   ```
2. Obtenemos la parte decimal

   ```
   SELECT TRIM('0' FROM FORMAT(@number - FLOOR(@number), 4, @locale))
   # .02
   ```
3. Y las unimos

   ```
   SELECT CONCAT(
     FORMAT(FLOOR(@number), 0, @locale),
     TRIM('0' FROM FORMAT(@number - FLOOR(@number), 4, @locale))
   )
   # 89,320.02
   ```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CiHmB9ZxzSw9iukoHC6jG/0)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias. No se me había ocurrido. Y de hecho concuerdo con ambos, pero como en este caso ese valor formateado no lo ocupo para nada más, me parece mejor traerlo directamente así para evitarme problemas.